# Hot to get HttpServletRequest from MockExternalContext

Tags: spring-webflow

Now I'm working on a spring web-flow unit test. I have to retrieve "HttpServletRequest" from MockExternalContext. But MockExternalContext don't support providing HttpServletRequest.How can I do to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MockHttpServletRequest is not a wrapper around HttpServletRequest, but rather its substitution for unit tests without servlet container. It can give you everything HttpServletRequest gives. Can you describe why do you need HttpServletRequest?

Comment: Can you tell me how I'd set a cookie in a webflow unit test?